# connecting a website to its database

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm creating a website for the first time all by myself. I'm doing the logic in Java (I use Ubuntu), and I have written the SQL script for the data base on windows using pgAdmin3 (postgresql).
How do I connect my java program to its database?

Answer (score 0):

If its just java and mysql, then you can try something like this

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName", "username","password");
```

As in the example below

```
   public boolean isIdInDb(String id) throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName", "username","password");
        String rawInfoDb = "select user_id from users ";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery(rawInfoDb);

        boolean isIt = false;
        while(rSet.next()){
            if(id.equals(rSet.getString(1))){
               isIt = true; 
            }
        }
        return isIt;
    }
```